# Azure role based - Web and API using same app roles

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have the following scenario. A net core web site and a net core web api. Web site needs to call the api. I'm securing both sites using Azure AD. I can authenticated the user and call the api using a jwt token. I want to use appRoles to control the access to the pages of the web site and the methods of the api.

I can do that editing the manifest of the web site and adding the appRoles that I want to use. At Enterprise applications->Users and groups I can add users to the roles. So after that I can secure my web pages using something like [Authorize(Roles = "AdminMember")]

I can do the same with the API.

Both applications use the same roles and same users, so my question is:

is possible to configure the appRoles only once? If I have a lot of users I need to configure in both Enterprise applications. If I remove or change something I need to do the same in both apps.
Can I use the roles defined in the api or web site in the other application in some way?

is it any way to have a central point to configure the roles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD, the Groups are equivalent to roles. So, you create Group and then add the required users to that group. So, when those users are authenticated their token will have claims which will have group info which they are part of. So, yes you can use the same groups for all the apps which are registered in that instance of the Azure AD.

So the way it will work is as follows :

In you app registration manifest file you set "groupMembershipClaims" : "SecurityGroup". In your .net core API you do

```
services.AddAuthorization( options => {
      options.AddPolicy("admin-only", p => {
            p.RequireClaim("groups","id of your admin group");    
      });
});
```

In your controller action you do

```
[Authorize("admin-only")]
```

If the user is added to the admin group and tries to access the above action, it will be success otherwise the user will be denied. Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't use groups...only approles. After logged in the web site I need to have at the User.Identity the same approles that I have at the api but only defining them in one place. If I request for an access token using the scope of the api I can retrieve the roles of the api inside the jwt token. But  I dont know to use that to authorize or not the Web site controllers

Comment: Follow [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/Controllers/AccountController.cs) link. Its recommended approach to use app roles to authorize actions in api controllers. And [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#:~:text=Declare%20roles%20for%20an%20application,and%20from%20their%20group%20membership) link to configure app roles in Azure AD.

Comment: I know how to protect the api and the we site using the approles. But I'm still having the problem to declare in two places the approles. So when I login in the Web site User.Identity.Claims comes from one app registration and api claims inside jwt token comes from another app registration. And I need to mantain both app registrations. I want to use only one app registration. For example create approles only at the api app registration and after login in the Web site update the user.identity with claims from api. Or I dont know if it's possible to retrieve api claims in the login proccess

Comment: Usually, the roles are set on the api app registration. What is your need to have app roles configured on client app registration? So, the usual flow is you make call from your front-end app to get token which will have app roles and then you use the same to determine what you want to show/hide on client app and same token is sent to the back-end which will authorize you to different actions you can perform on back-end api.

Comment: I login in the web site and after the Microsoft  login I'm redirected to my site. If I want to open another page protected with a role...when I get the jwt token with the claims? I know how to retrieve the token but not in which pont do it and how to add to each request inside the web site. Everytime I call the Api I need to send the jwt token in the headers...but how to do that when is a call between web pages ?

Comment: What is your front end application technology?

Comment: Net core with Razor pages

Comment: OK. Can you share your website code where you handle website access based on app roles?

Comment: This is done by Microsoft Identity using services.AddSignIn(Configuration);....after login User.Identity is filled with user info including roles. But If I try to obtain jwt token using GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scope) the token has not include the user roles.

Comment: OK. A lot depends on how you have configured your services in startup. Can you share your startup file contents?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/Startup.cs) example to make sure if you have not missed any thing obvious.

Comment: I'm using exactly the code from the sample. Even I used the same project and when I called to the GraphApi roles are not included in the jwt token, so I think that is not possible to do that. Maybe there is no other option that added both roles and users to both app registrations